# How to randomly change order of an array on click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, random

I am trying to write a simple dice game in React, which randomizes the order of players before play begins.

I am trying to use a function for shuffling arrays which has worked in a vanilla JavaScript version of the game I wrote:

```
export default function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    return array;
  }
}
```

(I took this code from [here](https://javascript.info/array-methods#shuffle-an-array)
originally and added the 'return array' out of desperation though it wasn't needed in my plain JavaScript version).

I have tried two ways of achieving what I want to do in React, first with a function called on click:

```
function shufflePlayers () {
    const shuffledPlayers=shuffle([...players]);
    setPlayers(shuffledPlayers);
  }
```

Which is then passed as a prop to the "Play!" button:

```
{play === false && players.length > 0 && <PlayButton togglePlay={togglePlay} shufflePlayers={shufflePlayers}/>}`
```

And then used like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function PlayButton(props) {
   function handleClick () {
     props.shufflePlayers();
     props.togglePlay();
   }
    return (
    <>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Play!</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Before being rendered like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function PlayButton(props) {
    function handleClick () {
      // props.shufflePlayers();
      props.togglePlay();
    }
    return (
    <>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Play!</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

This does not crash, but it does not change the order of the players on screen.

The other way I have tried is with useEffect:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    const shuffledPlayers=shuffle([...players]);
    setPlayers(shuffledPlayers);
  },[play])
```

Note that `play` is a Boolean which is false when setting up the game (adding/removing players) and true when playing the game.

And following error messages:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    const shuffledPlayers=shuffle([...players]);
    setPlayers(shuffledPlayers);
  },[players])
```

Note that `players` is an array of player objects.

But these either throw errors or appear to get stuck in an infinite loop as nothing renders.

I tried all of the above, and also consulted the following Stack Exchange threads:

[React Hooks: Shuffle array immediately on load, and onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540873/react-hooks-shuffle-array-immediately-on-load-and-onclick)

[unable to shuffle array correctly in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65027008/unable-to-shuffle-array-correctly-in-react)

From these I got the idea of spreading the array before sending it to my function.

So my question is, **how can I reliably re-order the players when the user clicks the "Play" button, and changes the `play` state variable from false to true?** (I don't mind at this stage if it means the order of players will be randomized again when the player returns to the start after a game is reset).

Comment: whats the error message is showing when you use useEffect ?

Comment: You probably should move the `return result`  *after*  your loop.

Comment: Is `players` initialized as `null` or an empty array `[]`?

Answer (score 2):

This code is bad form. It will infinitely loop.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const shuffledPlayers = shuffle([...players]);
  setPlayers(shuffledPlayers);
}, [players]);
```

You should use the function version instead:

```js
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setPlayers((currentPlayers) => shuffle([...currentPlayers]));
}, []);
```

Also, you want to be as immutable as possible when using React. Spreading the array into the shuffle function will pass a copy into it, but you have to make sure you return.

```js
/* Does not modify the incoming array */
const shuffle = (array) => {
  const sortedArr = structuredClone(array);
  for (let i = sortedArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [sortedArr[i], sortedArr[j]] = [sortedArr[j], sortedArr[i]];
  }
  return sortedArr;
}

const players = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
const shuffledPlayers = shuffle(players);

console.log(...shuffledPlayers);  // <random>
console.log(...players);          // [one, two, three, four]
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @derpirscher, the issue was with how I was trying to do things in React, but with my shuffle function, the return being inside the loop. Correcting the shuffle function to:

```
export default function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array; 
}
```

meant that I could call the shufflePlayers function as a prop of the Play! button.